# Gulp-Mocha delay before performing test

Tags: node.js, gulp-mocha

The normal version of Mocha supports delays before executings tests (link: https://mochajs.org/#hooks).

Is there a way to do this in gulp-mocha?

Answer (score 0):

The tests syntax **remains the same** when using `gulp-mocha` in compare to simple `mocha`

Actually, `gulp-mocha` is just a wrapper to help you run test suites via `gulp`

Comment: I got an error saying the function `run` is not defined when trying it the way it was described on the website.

Comment: could you please update your post with the code of your `gulpfile` and the code of test file, where error was thrown?

Comment: It's not that the code breaks, it is just a general question on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to fix this issue is to make an asynchronous test.

```
describe('StackOverflowExample', function() {
    it('Demonstrates how to create a test with delay', async function(done) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            //Your code here
            done();
        }, 250); //Set the delay to your liking
    });
});
```